# Hyperledger Fabric JSON response has backslashes

Tags: json, go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm currently testing a Hyperledger Fabric Application, but I get an unexpected JSON response.
Why are there extra backslashes between every object in the response?

```
result, err := json.Marshal(history)
logger.Debug(string(result))
if err != nil {
    message := fmt.Sprintf("unable to marshal the result: %s", err.Error())
    logger.Error(message)
    return shim.Error(message)
}

logger.Info("SimpleChaincode.getHistory exited successfully")
return shim.Success(result)
```

Actual CLI output:

```
Chaincode invoke successful. result: status:200 payload:"[{\"type\":\"history\",\"key\":\"key\",\"values\":[{\"tx_id\":\"723a398362282d92f7b05b821fc8f835736b6068e5d1b72d105fc86d6e57d64e\",\"value\":\"initial_value\",\"is_delete\":false}]}]"
```

Expected CLI result:

```
Chaincode invoke successful. 
result: status:200 
payload:
[
   {
      "type":"history",
      "key":"key",
      "values":[
         {
            "tx_id":"723a398362282d92f7b05b821fc8f835736b6068e5d1b72d105fc86d6e57d64e",
            "value":"initial_value",
            "is_delete":false
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Docker logs:

```
2020-08-19 14:40:18.823 UTC [SimpleChaincode] Debug -> DEBU 015 [{"type":"history","key":"key","values":[{"tx_id":"723a398362282d92f7b05b821fc8f835736b6068e5d1b72d105fc86d6e57d64e","value":"initial_value","is_delete":false}]}]
2020-08-19 14:40:18.823 UTC [SimpleChaincode] Info -> INFO 016 SimpleChaincode.getHistory exited successfully
```

Comment: The backslashes are not between things, they are in front of double-quotes. In some computer languages, literal double-quotes need to be escaped with backslashes in strings. Sometimes strings are *shown* with the escape characters added even though they are not actually in the string.

Comment: This is clearly doubled encoded JSON. Are you sure you're supposed to call json.Marshal?

Comment: @Peter history here is just a struct with 3 values (type, key, date) so it wouldn't work without json.Marshal. shim.Success() requires a byte slice.

Comment: As Andrew stated what you are seeing is correct, we wrap the response as a string, so the inner quotes have to be escaped. Go has no concept of Native JSON, it looks like you are expecting the response to be like that of Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Logging format

The logging format of the peer and orderer commands is controlled via the FABRIC_LOGGING_FORMAT environment variable. This can be set to a format string, such as the default

```
"%{color}%{time:2006-01-02 15:04:05.000 MST} [%{module}] %{shortfunc} -> %{level:.4s} %{id:03x}%{color:reset} %{message}"
```

to print the logs in a human-readable console format. It can be also set to json to output logs in JSON format.

Link: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/logging-control.html#logging-format

You can update core.yaml or you can use "FABRIC_LOGGING_FORMAT" in your docker compose file.

An example with core.yaml is given below:

```
    # Logging section for the chaincode container
logging:
  # Default level for all loggers within the chaincode container
  level:  info
  # Override default level for the 'shim' logger
  shim:   warning
  # Format for the chaincode container logs
  format: json
```

You can find core.yaml into "fabric-samples/config" directory.

Link: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/sampleconfig/core.yaml

If you download latest fabric samples, you can find sample core.yaml at "fabric-samples/config" directory.

An example with "FABRIC_LOGGING_FORMAT" in your docker compose file is given below:
You have to edit the environment of cli container with "- FABRIC_LOGGING_FORMAT=json"

```
  cli:
container_name: cli
image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
tty: true
stdin_open: true
environment:
  - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
  - FABRIC_LOGGING_FORMAT=json
  - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
  - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
command: /bin/bash
volumes:
    - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/chaincode
    - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
    - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
depends_on:
  - orderer.example.com
  - peer0.org1.example.com
  - peer1.org1.example.com
  - peer0.org2.example.com
  - peer1.org2.example.com
networks:
  - byfn
```

Comment: I tried the above way, CLI output remains same, Only logs on orederer/peers got changed e.g. {"level":"warn","ts":1647903913.6004941,"name":"gossip.discovery","caller":"discovery/discovery_impl.go:159","msg":"Could not connect to Endpoint: admin.net.sumit.io:7051, InternalEndpoint: admin.net.sumit.io:7051, PKI-ID: <nil>, Metadata:  : admin.net.sumit.io:7051 isn't in our organization, cannot be a bootstrap peer"}

Comment: No Worries, it works. In my case I was running peer command from terminal, so just added this and it works : export FABRIC_LOGGING_FORMAT=json, but now to shows extra slashes