# How to nicely format ("pretty print") Fabric chaincode query output?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm trying to generate a nicely formatted view of a specific ledger entry (or range of entries) with all related values.

When I run a chaincode query, I get an output like the following:

```
user@server:~/fabric-samples/test-network$ peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C mychannel -n myFirstChaincode --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles $PEER1_TLS -c '{"function":"queryOrder","Args":["004"]}'
2020-11-08 16:01:05.166 UTC [chaincodeCmd] chaincodeInvokeOrQuery -> INFO 001 Chaincode invoke successful. result: status:200 payload:"{\"actualDimensions\":{\"DIM1\":{},\"DIM2\":{},\"DIM3\":{},\"DIM4\":{}},\"customer\":\"GM\",\"dueDate\":\"tomorrow\",\"manufacturer\":\"undefined\",\"manufacturingData\":{},\"numOfDims\":\"5\",\"orderStatus\":\"new\",\"partID\":\"004\",\"partName\":\"Test Part\",\"requiredDimensions\":{\"DIM1\":{},\"DIM2\":{},\"DIM3\":{},\"DIM4\":{}}}"
```

This output looks like a long JSON string that has newlines replaced with `\`.

I'm looking for a human readable output.  While I can read this above entry, the associated data structure is very simple.  If I query another entry with several nested objects, it quickly becomes too messy to easily read.

I've tried adding something like `JSON.stringify(value,null,4)` to the chaincode query function, but that doesn't help:

```
2020-11-07 23:40:41.964 UTC [chaincodeCmd] chaincodeInvokeOrQuery -> INFO 001 Chaincode invoke successful. result: status:200 payload:"{\n    \"actualDimensions\": {\n        \"DIM1\": {},\n        \"DIM2\": {},\n        \"DIM3\": {},\n        \"DIM4\": {}\n    },\n    \"customer\": \"GM\",\n    \"dueDate\": \"tomorrow\",\n    \"manufacturer\": \"undefined\",\n    \"manufacturingData\": {},\n    \"numOfDims\": \"5\",\n    \"orderStatus\": \"new\",\n    \"partID\": \"004\",\n    \"partName\": \"Test Part\",\n    \"requiredDimensions\": {\n        \"DIM1\": {},\n        \"DIM2\": {},\n        \"DIM3\": {},\n        \"DIM4\": {}\n    }\n}"
```

It seems that the peer command may be formatting the output after JSON.stringify...

[This page](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/logging-control.html#logging-format) suggests that you can modify the logging format used for the peer command with an environmental variable, though I didn't find any examples or details of this beyond that one webpage.
When I tried adding an environmental variable to my cli:
`export FABRIC_LOGGING_FORMAT=json`, it didn't much help (it added more '/' instead of newlines):

```
student@hlfmc:~/fabric-samples/test-network$ peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C mychannel -n basic --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles $PEER1_TLS --peerAddresses localhost:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles $PEER2_TLS -c '{"function":"GetAllAssets","Args":[]}'
{"level":"info","ts":1605042675.2069416,"name":"chaincodeCmd","caller":"chaincode/common.go:160","msg":"Chaincode invoke successful. result: status:200 payload:\"[{\\\"Key\\\":\\\"asset1\\\",\\\"Record\\\":{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"asset1\\\",\\\"Color\\\":\\\"blue\\\",\\\"Size\\\":5,\\\"Owner\\\":\\\"Tomoko\\\",\\\"AppraisedValue\\\":300,\\\"docType\\\":\\\"asset\\\"}},{\\\"Key\\\":\\\"asset2\\\",\\\"Record\\\":{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"asset2\\\",\\\"Color\\\":\\\"red\\\",\\\"Size\\\":5,\\\"Owner\\\":\\\"Brad\\\",\\\"AppraisedValue\\\":400,\\\"docType\\\":\\\"asset\\\"}},{\\\"Key\\\":\\\"asset3\\\",\\\"Record\\\":{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"asset3\\\",\\\"Color\\\":\\\"green\\\",\\\"Size\\\":10,\\\"Owner\\\":\\\"Jin Soo\\\",\\\"AppraisedValue\\\":500,\\\"docType\\\":\\\"asset\\\"}},{\\\"Key\\\":\\\"asset4\\\",\\\"Record\\\":{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"asset4\\\",\\\"Color\\\":\\\"yellow\\\",\\\"Size\\\":10,\\\"Owner\\\":\\\"Max\\\",\\\"AppraisedValue\\\":600,\\\"docType\\\":\\\"asset\\\"}},{\\\"Key\\\":\\\"asset5\\\",\\\"Record\\\":{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"asset5\\\",\\\"Color\\\":\\\"black\\\",\\\"Size\\\":15,\\\"Owner\\\":\\\"Adriana\\\",\\\"AppraisedValue\\\":700,\\\"docType\\\":\\\"asset\\\"}},{\\\"Key\\\":\\\"asset6\\\",\\\"Record\\\":{\\\"ID\\\":\\\"asset6\\\",\\\"Color\\\":\\\"white\\\",\\\"Size\\\":15,\\\"Owner\\\":\\\"Michel\\\",\\\"AppraisedValue\\\":800,\\\"docType\\\":\\\"asset\\\"}}]\" "}
```

(The above test was run on a separate server using the stock ["asset-transfer-basic"](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/asset-transfer-basic) sample chaincode.)
Note: I also tried updating the fabric-samples/config/core.yaml file with "format: json" and then re-running the chaincode (after properly bringing everything down and freshly starting the network).  This gave the same output as before (no change from original output).  I also tried editing the peer docker container's internal core.yaml file at /etc/hyperledger/fabric/core.yaml, which also did not appear to affect the output.

I've also tried calling the chaincode from an application (as opposed to directly from the CLI).  The resulting output string no longer has '/'  (but still no newlines/indentation):

```
user@server$ node query2.js 
Wallet path: /home/user/Project/application/wallet
Transaction has been evaluated, result is: {"actualDimensions":{"DIM1":{},"DIM2":{},"DIM3":{},"DIM4":{}},"customer":"GM","dueDate":"tomorrow","manufacturer":"undefined","manufacturingData":{},"numOfDims":"5","orderStatus":"new","partID":"004","partName":"Test Part","requiredDimensions":{"DIM1":{},"DIM2":{},"DIM3":{},"DIM4":{}}}
```

If I try to use JSON.stringify on the output string, I get the '/' again:

```
user@server$ node query2.js
Wallet path: /home/user/Project/application/wallet
Transaction has been evaluated, result is: "{\"actualDimensions\":{\"DIM1\":{},\"DIM2\":{},\"DIM3\":{},\"DIM4\":{}},\"customer\":\"GM\",\"dueDate\":\"tomorrow\",\"manufacturer\":\"undefined\",\"manufacturingData\":{},\"numOfDims\":\"5\",\"orderStatus\":\"new\",\"partID\":\"004\",\"partName\":\"Test Part\",\"requiredDimensions\":{\"DIM1\":{},\"DIM2\":{},\"DIM3\":{},\"DIM4\":{}}}"
```

Here's the application code: (line 48 is original; 46-47 is second version)

```
 45   ¦ ¦ ¦ const result = await contract.evaluateTransaction('queryOrder','004');
 46   ¦ ¦ ¦ const stringResult=result.toString();
 47   ¦ ¦ ¦ console.log(`Transaction has been evaluated, result is: ${JSON.stringify(stringResult,null,4)}`);
 48   ¦ ¦ ¦ //console.log(`Transaction has been evaluated, result is: ${result.toString()}`);
```

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63489723/hyperledger-fabric-json-response-has-backslashes) with a similar question, but it did not provide any solution for pretty formatting.

Are there any current solutions/suggestions for this?

I'd be happy with JSON formatting or anything else that has spacing/newlines and makes the current output more human-readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can update core.yaml or you can use "FABRIC_LOGGING_FORMAT" in your docker compose file.

An example with core.yaml is given below:

```
    # Logging section for the chaincode container
logging:
  # Default level for all loggers within the chaincode container
  level:  info
  # Override default level for the 'shim' logger
  shim:   warning
  # Format for the chaincode container logs
  format: json
```

You can find core.yaml into "fabric-samples/config" directory.

Link: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/sampleconfig/core.yaml

If you download latest fabric samples, you can find sample core.yaml at "fabric-samples/config" directory.

An example with "FABRIC_LOGGING_FORMAT" in your docker compose file is given below:
You have to edit the environment of cli container with "- FABRIC_LOGGING_FORMAT=json"

```
  cli:
container_name: cli
image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
tty: true
stdin_open: true
environment:
  - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
  - FABRIC_LOGGING_FORMAT=json
  - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
  - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
command: /bin/bash
volumes:
    - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/chaincode
    - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
    - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
depends_on:
  - orderer.example.com
  - peer0.org1.example.com
  - peer1.org1.example.com
  - peer0.org2.example.com
  - peer1.org2.example.com
networks:
  - byfn
```

Comment: Hi Ta-seen Junaid, thank you for your reply!

Do you know what format arguments can be used to improve the formatting of the output (e.g. insert proper newlines and spacing)?  I'm still not sure how to do this part (or if it can be done using core.yaml or the FABRIC_LOGGING_FORMAT environment variable.)

Comment: Hi Ta-seen Junaid, thank you for your response and edit.  Since I don't have a cli container in the latest fabric samples that I'm using, I added the "  - FABRIC_LOGGING_FORMAT=json" variable to both peer nodes.  However it did not change the output. I tried setting the variable directly in the CLI - this time, it changed the output, but instead of adding newlines, it added additional '/'.  (See the code output I added in my edited post.)

Comment: You can find core.yaml into "fabric-samples/config" directory. Pleasse update "format: json" in core.yaml. I updated my answer too. Both core.yaml & docker compose  file worked for me.

Comment: Yeah, you are using peer cli, instead of container. Link:https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html#interacting-with-the-network

Comment: Hello Ta-seen Junaid, I added "format: json" to fabric-samples/config/core.yaml, cleaned up the network (./network down) and restarted the network and chaincode - I still got the '/' in my output.  I also tried logging into the peer container and modifying the peer's internal core.yaml (located at /etc/hyperledger/fabric/core.yaml), and re-running the chaincode, but still received the same output.